# Example webpage plays sound

Tags: html, audio

I'm trying to create a very simple webpage for a native language course. What I want is very simple: I have text that when it's clicked will play the equivalent sound file. However I'm a newbie on this, and I'm pretty sure there must be a simple out there, preferably already using HTML5, from which I can draw inspiration or use as template. Can anyone recommend me one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<audio id="myTune">
  <source src="path/to/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').play()">Play Music</button>
```

This is html5's way of embedding an audio clip. If you want the button to just appear as text you can apply some simple css to it like so:

```
button {
  background:none!important;
  border:none; 
  padding:0!important;
  color:black;

  /* Make the cursor look like it is over a button. 
     Just remove this line if you want the cursor to 
     stay the same when you hover over the text */
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) should be helpful. It's an explanation of the audio tag for html 5 and what browsers it is compatible with.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to add a single element. I've already coem accross that page (first link on Google when you look for HTML5 and audio). But what I want is a page that lists various file, with a tag behind it, and plays the sound when clicking on it. Probably that's basic HTML, but as I said, I'm a newbie.

Comment: @Rui I made a couple of edits to the post. Were those edits not what your looking for? It seems like a button that looks like text and plays music is what you were asking for. But I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Hi, that's exactly the info I was looking. Thanks.